# UIButton.frame.origin.y is not the correct value

Tags: ios, swift, position, autolayout, frame

I have a button that has a bottom-space-to-Superview constraint with a constant of 0 which places it right on the bottom of the screen. Visually when I run the app that is exactly what is happening - the button is on the bottom of the screen. In code, I want to get the button's frame.origin.y so I could place other objects programmatically above the button.

The frame.origin.y + the frame.height should equal the height of the screen since it is placed right up against the bottom, but the values I'm getting from checking the UIButton's frame are not correct.

Using println to see the values:

```
println("HomeBtn starts: \(homeBtn.frame.origin.y)")
println("HomeBtn height: \(homeBtn.frame.height)")
println("Screen height: \(self.view.frame.height)")
```

Here are the results...

On the iPhone 6+:

```
HomeBtn starts: 528.0
HomeBtn height: 72.0
Screen height: 736.0
```

On the iPhone 5:

```
HomeBtn starts: 528.0
HomeBtn height: 72.0
Screen height: 568.0
```

On an iPad:

```
HomeBtn starts: 528.0
HomeBtn height: 72.0
Screen height: 1024.0
```

The 528 and 72 correspond to the values shown for the HomeBtn in the Storyboard/Interface Builder, but with Autolayout and different device sizes, these values should change per device.

Is there a better solution to getting a UIView's location (whether button/imageView/label/etc) after it's been placed by Autolayout rather than using its frame.origin and frame.height/width values?

Comment: Where are you checking the frame information?  It isn't valid until `viewDidLayoutSubviews` because Auto Layout hasn't run yet.

Comment: @vacawama that is the correct answer! I was still using viewDidLoad - post it as an answer and I'll mark it correct. Thanks so much for knocking this back in my head.   =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The frame information for the subviews isn't set up until *Auto Layout* runs.  Your first opportunity to see the layout of the subviews is in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    // Now that the views are all laid out, we can check their positions.
    println("HomeBtn starts: \(homeBtn.frame.origin.y)")
    println("HomeBtn height: \(homeBtn.frame.height)")
    println("Screen height: \(self.view.frame.height)") 
}
```

Comment: So is there a best strategy for setting values for your frame's positioning? viewDidLayoutSubviews gets called twice, viewDidLoad is too early, but viewDidAppear can be too late to call the code - so that views show up blank when they first appear

Comment: The best strategy is to fully embrace Auto Layout.  You can specify constraints in code for your new views that you are adding through code.